# What is a total $0/1$-valued function"?

Tags: terminology, computability

I have seen this expression

[image]

What is the definition used here?

Comment: Just the phrase "0/1-valued function" suggests that the function's codomain is the set $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: If I hear "n-valued function" I think the mean $f(x)$ may have multiple outputs (violating the standard definition of "function" which is practically writ in stone that a well-defined function has a single output for each point in the domain).  For example $f:[-1,1]\to [0,2\pi)$ via $f(x) = \theta$ if $\sin \theta x$ is a 2-value "function".  But in this context I really actually have no idea.

Comment: "retty sure that "0/1-valued" means that the output is always 0 or 1."  and "Just the phrase "0/1-valued function" suggests that the function's codomain is the set {0,1}".  D'oh!  That is almost *certainly* the case....

Comment: It's from a class on Theory of Computation, topic: Recursive and Recursively Enumerable Sets. "total" here means there's always an output (never undefined) so I think 1st commenter is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\phi_x:{\Bbb N}_0^k\rightarrow {\Bbb N}_0$ is a total 0/1-valued function means that the domain of $\phi_x$ is ${\Bbb N}_0^k$ and the range is $\phi({\Bbb N}_0^k)\subseteq \{0,1\}$.